# How can I XML serialize a synchronized ArrayList?

Tags: serialization, synchronization, xml-serialization, java

When I try to serialize and deserialize an `ArrayList` wrapped in `Collections.synchronizedList` using `beans.XMLEncoder` and `beans.XMLDecoder`, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException  
Continuing ...  
java.lang.Exception: XMLEncoder: discarding statement XMLEncoder.writeObject*Collections$SynchronizedRandomAccessList);  
Continuing ...
```

Since the program I am working on is a multithreaded music library client/server application, I need the synchronization. If using an ordinary ArrayList, the serialization/deserialization works fine. I really don't want to use Vector, since it contains a lot of legacy operations.

Here are my methods to serialize and deserialize:

```
/**  
* Serializes library into an XML file  
* @param xmlFileLocation - location of XML file  
*/ 

public void saveLibrary (String xmlFileLocation) {  
    FileOutputStream fos;  
    try {  
        fos = new FileOutputStream(xmlFileLocation);  
        XMLEncoder encoder = new XMLEncoder(fos);  
        encoder.writeObject(lib);  
        encoder.close();  
        fos.close();  
    } catch (Exception e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();  
    }  
} 

/**  
* Constructor for Library, deserializes XML file  
* @param xmlFileLocation - location of XML file  
*/ 
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")  
public Library(String xmlFileLocation) {  
    FileInputStream fis;  
    try {  
        fis = new FileInputStream(xmlFileLocation);  
        XMLDecoder decoder = new XMLDecoder(fis);  
        Object o = decoder.readObject();  
        if (o instanceof List)    
            setLib((List<MusicDescription>) o);   
            decoder.close();  
            fis.close();  
    } catch (Exception e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }     
}
```

As I stated, I really don't want to use Vector, since it contains a lot of legacy operations.

Comment: Do you need that synchronisation while serialising though? I'd probably lock access to the list while I'm making a copy to a new `ArrayList`, then serialise the copy.

Comment: So, how do you copy the synchronized list to a non-synchronized one?

Comment: `synchronized (synchronizedList) { return new ArrayList<MusicDescription>(synchronizedList); }`

Comment: @JBNizet Exactly. Obviously `MusicDescription` has to be immutable too. But that's true with or without the serialisation.